# Most efficient way to play music with floppy drives

Tags: gpio, python, c++

I've been wanting to use my RPi as a controller for a floppy drive symphony for a long time. However, progress is going very slowly because I keep running into issues. Whenever I try to use more than one floppy drive with my current method, the Pi maxes out at 100% CPU usage and the notes barely play.

I'm using Python as the programming language, which is probably one of the main reasons why it runs slowly. But I'm not sure if changing to C++ would make it all that much faster.

So should I use Python or C++? What GPIO library should I use for that language? And what sort of technique should I use for playing the notes? Should it be multithreaded, or a type of queue of notes, or something entirely else?

Below is the link for the latest version I've made. It doesn't play a song yet, simply just two notes on two drives, and even that blasts the CPU usage to 100%.

http://pastebin.com/PrcH9ffs

Thanks in advance. More descriptive answers are appreciated :)

Comment: It's definitely been done before, with at least some parts in Python: https://github.com/jereksel/MidiToFloppy/tree/master/RPi

Comment: All of the playing is done in C. Python is just used for conversions.